# Mount and blade Warband

Tags: command-line, mount, steam, chromebook

Two problems.
First, Mount and Blade won't run in Ubuntu 12.04; I am using Crouton with an Acer Chromebook 11. 
When I click play Steam instantly shuts down. I think I have the required specs to run the game.

I read around and it could be that I haven't given it the rights to launch or something at which point I need to enter something in the Terminal.
However that specific command line starts with a "~" and for some reason when I'm in Ubuntu when I hit the same key it gives me a straight bar, while in Chrome OS I can type it as you see.

Another weird thing is that I can't just copy paste the command line, paste isn't working; I've tried `Ctrl+V` and `Ctrl+Shift+V` and both don't work.

So three questions:

1. Why could M&B not work?
2. How do I copy paste something in the Terminal in Ubuntu?
3. How do I type the ~ in Ubuntu if the key it's supposed to be bound to doesn't result in a ~?

Comment: maybe useful: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33659

Answer (score 0):

- 1. idk ,run from terminal
- 2. 3-rd m-button / shift-insert
- 3. don't worry ,it holds well,just don't look at the monitor and press enter